# Server 2008 Safemode Reboot Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, safe-mode

I'm trying to get into my 2k8 DC, which is hanging on applying policy settings, but thats a DNS issue that I can fix once getting into safemode.

Rebooted in safemode both without and with networking, got to the login screen and it just restarts itself. I'm pretty confident I don't have a virus. This doesn't happen in normal mode. Server is controlled via a KVM switch if that makes any difference.

Comment: So even with the hanging at "applying policy settings" it DOES eventually let you log in via Normal Mode?

Comment: i haven't actually gotten past applying policy settings yet. I'm sure i will within a few hours but i'd rather fix the problem in a minute than wait for hours.

Comment: OK, so how do you know that the reboot "doesn't happen in normal mode?"  Or is it the applying user policy settings it's hanging on (_after_ login)?

Comment: You are right, I don't know it doesn't happen in normal mode, but it hasn't happened yet and it's been applying policy settings for a while. I rebooted yesterday just fine, then today made the dns change and messed things up bad for myself.

I'll bite my foot if it does. But either way I'm no closer to solving that reboot problem. 

Would you recommend running repair from the OS cd? I know it wont fix the DNS problem but could it fix the reboot issue in safemode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unplug it from the network does it boot normally (ie- not safe mode) any faster?  Thinking that it's going to time things out with no network faster than it will otherwise.

Comment: Great idea! Got my login screen on normal boot

Comment: Sweet, can you log in now?  Or does it reboot on you still?  If you can get in, I'd still suggest running CHKDSK, not being able to login into Safe Mode is pretty weird, even on a DC. :)

Comment: Logged in fine and fixed the problem. Dare me to restart again?

Comment: Yeah, but boot into safe mode! If faulty DNS (client or server) settings causes 'safe mode with no networking' to reboot a DC, I wanna know what you did to that DNS! :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess (based on what you're telling me) is that you have a hardware (or at least a file system) issue.

Boot from the Server 2008 install disk and use the “Repair your computer” option.  It'll give you three options including Command Prompt.

Use that to run a CHKDSK and see if it thinks anything is up with the file system. If it says there is, then you'll want to rerun CHKDSK with the repair option(s) switched on (usually /F, might be different in the 2008 repair console you'll be going into via the DVD, so do a chkdsk /? to figure out what the exact switch options are).

If that doesn't help I'd say next test the hard drives by using the manufacturer's diagnostics, and if that comes up clean then start testing the memory using [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) (for a day or more, we usually aim for 72+ hours of continuous memory tests before we claim it's 'OK').

HTH.